How to Import MusicXML Files?
Are there any undocumented or third-party packages or paclets for importing MusicXML?
https://github.com/w3c/musicxml/releases

It's an ordinary XML format, so you can import it as XML via Import. You only have to disable reading the DTD file, because the links are broken.
Import["https://wpmedia.musicxml.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/MozaVeilSample.musicxml", 
 "XML", "ReadDTD" -> False]
(* XMLObject["Document"][ ... ] *)


Awesome thanks. Do you know if is there any more integration than raw xml, i.e. some parsing, or maybe generating Audio or Midi or something? The motivation here is to have a back and forth between MMA and MuseScore 4.0
